# Return false if char or string, but return true if input cannot convert to an integer. C++ Do while loop

Tags: c++

Language: C++ (IDE: Visual Studios)
How do I make a do while loop return true when a user inputs anything but an integer? I'm a little lost on how to do this.

```
#include <iostream>//pre processor directive
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;//standard library

int main( )

double money=0;

do{
    cout << ("please enter your taxable income:\n") << fixed << setprecision(2) << endl;

    cin >> (money);

}while(money < 0 || );
```

Comment: `#include <iostream>//pre processor directive` - `<3`.

Comment: I have more code but this is the only section of the code that I need an answer to.

Comment: Hint: `std::istream` provides an `operator bool()` that lets it be converted to a boolean.

Comment: I appreciate the hint, I'll look into it.

Comment: @JORDANO, The link in the answer is your best friend here.

Comment: Users don't input integers; they input text. The question should be "how do I return false if the text is not convertible to an integer", and at that point the answer should be obvious: try to convert it and if the conversion fails, return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just doing a try/catch statement, which basically involved me adding a new variable to the mix, which is the string "str":

```
    double money = 0; //initialized
    string str= ""; //initialized

    do{

        cout << "Please input an integer value" << endl;
        cin >> (str);

        try{
            money = stod(str);   //string to double
        }catch(...){  //inside the parenthesis, the "..." means to catch all exceptions.
            money = -1;    
            cin.clear();   
        }

    }while( money < 0);
```

This will catch anything that does not convert to a double, giving the value of money to equal -1. Otherwise, it will continue with the program.

Answer (score 5):

[`istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) defines a [conversion to `bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) which indicates whether the last read was successful. You can use this to test whether parsing a `double` succeeded:

```
if (cin >> money) {
    // success
} else {
    // failure
}
```

If the stream is in a failed state and you want to retry reading—e.g., to prompt the user for a new value—then you can use the [`clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) member function to return the state to normal:

```
cin.clear();
```

However, this does not clear the input buffer, so you will end up reading the same data again. You can clear the input buffer until the next newline character:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Or you can read by lines instead, and use a [`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to read individual values:

```
string line;
getline(cin, line);
istringstream stream(line);
if (stream >> money) {
    // success
} else {
    // failure
}
```

This has the advantage of forcing user input to be line-based—it’s token-based by default.

Comment: If the conversion fails you'll also want to clear the input buffer (in addition to the stream state) before retrying, otherwise you'll be caught in an endless loop.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Thanks, I should have mentioned that earlier. Updated.